# figure not centering properly

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I have a figure with a caption and it doesn't seem to center properly. It seems to left justify the figure:

```
\begin{figure}
{\centering\includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{figures/afigure}}

\protect\caption{Some Title\label{fig:some_label}}

\vspace{.3cm}

\footnotesize

A really nice description of the plot that you see above. It talks about all the interesting aspects of this plot. 

\normalsize

\end{figure}
```

Comment: it doesn't do any harm but `\protect` looks very odd there (it never does anything useful if it is not in the argument of some other command that needs it (a "moving argument")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices:

- Remove the pair of curly braces that enclose the `\centering` and `\includegraphics` statements.
- If you want to keep the pair of curly braces, insert `\par` just ahead of the closing curly brace, `}`.

Comment: could you elaborate on what's going on? i thought to keep the centering limited to the includegraphics i need to enclose it in {}?

Comment: @alex - See my edit: I've added a second option: to insert a `\par` statement just before the closing curly brace.

Comment: could you explain why that is happening though?

Comment: @Alex - What's "happening" is that `\centering` is applied at the *end* of what TeX considers to be "currently active paragraph". In your code, though, there's no paragraph break *inside* the group that contains the `\includegraphics` statement; hence, the `\centering` instruction ends up having no effect. To get the desired centering, either insert an explicit `\par` instruction inside the TeX group, or just omit the curly braces.